# Order from highest value

Tags: mysql

Hello I have an problem with ordering values. When you use this simple method

```
SELECT username, balance FROM '.$table_name.' ORDER BY balance DESC LIMIT 30
```

You'll get an order form highest number, but how can i make reverse of it, so it will show 30 lowest values in the table.

Comment: remove `DESC` from the order by, the data will then be sorted the opposite way.

Answer (score 2):

You just want to change from DESC to ASC. so,

```
SELECT username, balance FROM '.$table_name.' ORDER BY balance DESC LIMIT 30
```

becomes

```
SELECT username, balance FROM '.$table_name.' ORDER BY balance ASC LIMIT 30
```

SQL actually sorts by ASC by default, so you could leave out the `ASC`, but perhaps this way is more clear.

Comment: `ASC` is not needed in order to sort in ascending order. You can use `ORDER BY balance`